# brew extract --version=9.25 ghostscript [tap] what is tap?

Tags: homebrew

Tile says it all. Trying to install old version of ghostscript on a new mac.

`brew extract --version=9.25 ghostscript <tap>`

what should tap be? Or better how can one figure this out, teach me to fish.

Comment: Newer version of this question, with answer, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64125796/161366

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official [Homebrew terminology](https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook#homebrew-terminology), a tap is:

> A Git repository of Formulae and/or commands

They are located under:

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/
```

for Intel Mac, and under

```
/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/
```

for M1 Mac.

You can create a local tap with:

```
brew tap-new user/repo
```

This will create a local git repository under `/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/user/repo/`(for M1).

If you want to know more about tap, read the man page (`man brew`), read the [documentation](https://docs.brew.sh/), and if you want to know even more read the [source code](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew).